# Setting the first day of the week with the wx.lib.calendar.Calendar control?

Tags: python, calendar, wxpython

As per the title, is it possible to change the first day of the week (Monday instead of Sunday)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: you have to call `cal.SetBusType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wx.CAL_MONDAY_FIRST` value in the style argument of the constructir.

**Update**

Hier is code generated by wxGlade:

```
wx.calendar.CalendarCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.calendar.CAL_MONDAY_FIRST)
```

It has Monday in the leftmost column.

Comment: I've tried it using wx.calendar.CAL_MONDAY_FIRST but that doesn't have any effect - Sunday is still first.

Comment: @Noah I tried this using xwGlade and it works find. See may updated answer

Comment: I'm using wx.lib.calendar.Calendar(), not CalendarCtrl().